# Null string exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-access-token, facebook-insights

Before i ask my question i need to mention that i looked up in the site to solve the problem but i didnt find nothing.

Here is my function :

```
    public string GetAccessToken(int agencyId)
    {
        string retrunString = null;
        Token fbToken = tokenMgr.Get(agencyId, "FacebookInsights");
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbToken.AccessToken))  **
            return retrunString;
        else
            return fbToken.AccessToken;
    }
```

When Token is an object which include a String field  name : AccessToken.

When i debug the code and reach the line with the ' ** ' when fbToken.AccessToken is NULL , I get an exception " **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**"

When i looked up in other threads they suggest to use **String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace** , but it didnt solve the problem and i keep getting the error.

I would greatly appreciate any help , thanks in advance!

Comment: `fbToken` is probably null.

Comment: i know.. i already mention that..

Comment: `if (fbToken == null || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbToken.AccessToken))` would solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fbToken` is null, not `fbToken.AccessToken`. Use something like this:

```
if ( fbToken == null || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbToken.AccessToken) )
```

New C# 6.0 allows you to do [null propagation](http://www.filipekberg.se/2015/01/11/csharp-6-0-null-propagation/) to accomplish this as well:

```
if ( String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbToken?.AccessToken) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Write it like this. Check [**Null-conditional Operators**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx)

```
if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbToken?.AccessToken))
{
    //your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to validate the object `fbToken` and not his member `AccessToken`.

```
public string GetAccessToken(int agencyId)
{
    var fbToken = tokenMgr.Get(agencyId, "FacebookInsights");  
    return (fbToken == null) ? null : fbToken.AccessToken;
}
```